# How to remove overlapping elements in list of tuples?

Tags: python, tuples

I have a list of tuples

```
[('one','two','three'),('four','five','six'),('seven','eight','nine')]
```

and a list

```
['three','five','nine']
```

What I want to do is remove any elements of tuples that overlaps with the

second list so that I would have

```
[('one','two'),('four','six'),('seven','eight')]
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `[tuple(i for i in item if i not in B) for item in A]` ?

Comment: you can not remove anything from tuples, they are immutable. You need to create new ones that do not contain the elements you want to skip. Checking if an element is in something is best done with a `set()`. So: create a set of 3,5,6 and use the list comp of @jpp to create new tuples.

Answer (score 1):

```
listoflists = [('one','two','three'),('four','five','six'),('seven','eight','nine')]
toremove = ['three','five','nine']

outcome = [tuple(item for item in list if item not in toremove) for list in listoflists]
```

Comment: Hello, to help others understand your answer, consider including a short description of your code and how it solves the posted question.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new tuple list

```
a=[('one','two','three'),('four','five','six'),('seven','eight','nine')]
b=['three','five','nine']
[set(i).difference(b) for i in a] # if you do not care about the order inside the tuple
```